# Getting deployment limit error even though I am under the limit in IBM Watson Machine Learning

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-studio, cloud-pak-for-data

I get the "You have reached the deployment limit for your Watson Machine Learning plan..." error message even though I only have 2 models deployed at present. I had as many as 4 deployed previously (deleted them all last week after retraining the models), and should be allowed 5 with my account type.

Are old deployments being saved somehow and counting towards my limit?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You might try checking your other projects. If you have 2 models deployed in Project A and another 3 models deployed in Project B, it will be considered 5 deployed models. You can check the number of deployments by opening each project and clicking on the Deployments tab.

Comment: Appreciate the insight, but I only have one project going at the moment :(